# How to create spinning 3d object c#

Tags: c#, 3d, gdi+

How can I implement a 3d object of the letter L, without using any 3d libraries for this? I created 3d cube, but I can not create an object in the form of a letter.

Comment: Well 3d L can be a combination of two rectangles. What is stopping you from drawing that?

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to make a cube then you're (hopefully) on your way there already! You can think of all complex shapes as being a combination of simpler shapes. For example if you want to make an 'L' you can do so using a combination of rectangular prisms (or cubes although you'll need more). Try something like the following and have a think about how you would translate and rotate the objects to get the desired shape:

```
 _
| |  <- 2x1x1 rectangular prism
|_|_
|___| <- 2x1x1 rectangular prism rotated 90 degrees (or 1x2x1)
```

You can apply this logic for all your shapes :)